# Parse Docx file content w.r.t. headings

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to parse the structure of a docx file and its content using python-docx. The file ist structured using 'Heading 1' to 'Heading 6'. Under any heading content could be in form of an table element.

I understand how to extract the headings and the tables *independent of each other*, using python-docx:

```
    doc = Document("file.docx")
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style == doc.styles['Heading 1']:
            indent = 1
            result.append('- %s' % paragraph.text.strip())
        elif paragraph.style == doc.styles['Heading 2']:
            indent = 2
            result.append('  ' * indent + '- %s:' % paragraph.text.strip())
        elif paragraph.style == doc.styles['Heading 3']:
            indent = 3
            result.append('  ' * indent + '- %s:' % paragraph.text.strip())
        [...]
        else:
            [...]

    for table in doc.tables:
        if _is_content(table.row_cells(0)[0].text):
            result.add_table(table)
```

My problem is preserving the structure. How does I find out under with heading a table is in the source document?

Comment: In addition to answer below, search on "python-docx iter_block_items" for discussion and solutions on this topic. In particular, this page goes into detail: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the structured information from docx file using the xml.
Try this:

```
doc = Document("file.docx")
headings = [] #extract only headings from your code
tables = [] #extract tables from your code
tags = []
all_text = []
schema = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
for elem in doc.element.getiterator():
    if elem.tag == schema + 'body':
        for i, child in enumerate(elem.getchildren()):
            if child.tag != schema + 'tbl':
                 node_text = child.text
                 if node_text:
                     if node_text in headings:
                         tags.append('heading')
                     else:
                         tags.append('text')
                     all_text.append(node_text)
             else:
                 tags.append('table')
        break
```

After above code you will have the list of tags which will show the structure of document heading,text and table then you can map the respective data from the lists.